# Crystal Report dynamic parameter values do not show up in prompt when report is opened within SAP B1

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

Crystal Report dynamic parameter values do not show up in prompt when report is opened within SAP B1. However, it is working fine when the report is opened in Crystal Report Designer. Please help thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the report and initiate the parameter from inside Crystal Reports when on B1.

The list you see from outside only shows if you're using a parameter query like `@SELECT`, etc ...